# JScrollPane doesn't update scrollbar when window is maximized

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jsplitpane

In my GUI, I have a `JSplitPane` containing two `JTextArea` controls enclosed in a `JScrollPane`, all enclosed in a `JFrame`.

I am having problems with the scrollbar updating when the window is maximized. The scrollbar updates correctly when the window is minimized, but fails to appear when I try to create a new line in one of the text areas. It updates when I minimize the window, but I am trying to get the scroll bar to update when the window is maximized.

```
        this.text = new JTextArea(15, 70);

        this.text.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
        this.text.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        this.text.setLineWrap(true);

        //Create lines
        JTextArea lines = new JTextArea(15, 2);
        lines.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        int lineHeight = lines.getRows();
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= lineHeight + 1) {
            lines.append(Integer.toString(i) + "\n");
            i++;
        }
        lines.setEditable(false);

        //Pack it all

        JSplitPane combo = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, lines,
                this.text);
        combo.setResizeWeight(0d / 10d);

        //Create scrolling area

        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(combo);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

I have some more code regarding a menu and putting everything into a frame if that is important. I believe I am using the default layout manager.

Comment: Not sure why you are adding the split pane to the scroll pane. The size of the split pane does not change dynamically. The components added to the split pane (ie. the text area) can change dynamically. So you should add the text area to the scroll pane and the scroll pane to the split pane. Post a proper [mre] if you need more help.

Comment: @camickr That works perfectly. Thank you.